# Arguments object typecasting

Tags: javascript, function

Kindly I am a beginner in JavaScript world, and I have a question with the below simple example,

```
function myFun(){
    return arguments;
}

var myVar=myFun("a","b","c"); 

//1
console.log(myVar); //=>//["a", "b", "c", callee: function, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): function]

//2
for(m in myVar){
    console.log(m); //will generate only the realistic arguments "a","b","c".
}
```

According to the above snippet,
why should the first invoking generate the arguments object with the inherited properties from the Function main object, and the second will generate only the realistic arguments.

If we passed the arguments object to a second function, why should it will be passed with the realistic data only, for example

```
function foo(something) {
console.log(something); ///=>this will generate number 3 as parameter only, not the rest of the object
 return this.a + something;
}
var obj = {
 a: 2
};
var bar = function() {
 return foo.apply( obj, arguments );
};
var b = bar( 3 ); // 2 3
```

as pointed in the line of console.log(something), it will generate only the realistic params only

Comment: According to [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in): The `for...in` statement iterates over the **enumerable properties** of an object. Here is what [**enumerable properties means**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir : ok and what about the second example? the arguments object when passed as an argument to anther function, it will be passed only with the enumerable properties only.

Comment: Because each function has it's own `arguments` object, the `arguments`object of the `secondFun` will be an object that contain another object (the `arguments` object of the `firstFun`).

Comment: So if `firstFun`'s `arguments` objects looked like this: `{"0": "a", "1": "b", "2": "c", other stuff}`, then `secondFun`'s `arguments` object will look like this: `{"0":  {"0": "a", "1": "b", "2": "c", other stuff},  other stuff}`.

Comment: !!, you are talking about another question? , please run the second example firstly.

Comment: i don't have a problem of which output object will be dumped, i have a problem of why the arguments object when passed to another function it will be passed with the enumerable properties only, console.log(arguments) that passed as argument object , it will be a , b , c only without callee and prototype and the rest of the proeprties

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir : i will modify the last part of the question to be clear

Comment: It passes the whole object including its non-enumerable properties: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHh2x.jpg

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir : yes it is true , but look for the new edit as i mentioned.

Comment: `apply` works differently, `apply` expects an array, so if an array-like object is passed (`arguments` object is an array-like object), then only the properties that makes it look like an array are taken. `"0", "1", "2", ...` and the rest is ignored.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir : yes this is true, but MDN didn't talk about any typecasting, can you provide a reference to the point which indicates that a typecasting will happen?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOw2q.jpg I'm looking for a reference

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir : write an an answer as i wrote and i will give you the correct sign

Comment: I found the answer by mistake haha. Check the answer bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in the next example is what is interessting:

```js
function foo() { }

foo.apply(null, 5);
```

The error says (on google chrome):

> `CreateListFromArrayLike` is called on non-object.

So apparently `apply` calls that function first before passing the arguments to the function, `CreateListFromArrayLike` will create a new object (or array) out of the provided one ignoring any non-array-like properties in the process.

**Note:** On mozilla firefox, it throws a different error, but I think both browsers' engines have the same way of implementing `apply`.

Comment: Thank you Ibrahim.

Answer (score 1):

as  @ibrahim mahrir comments, and this article [this](http://www.intelligiblebabble.com/functional-javascript-part-3-apply-call-and-the-arguments-object)
I discovered that, apply will typecast the object to be an array, and this is an example,

```
  function toArray(args) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(args);
}

function firstFun(){
   console.log(toArray(arguments));
}
firstFun("A","b");
```

/// this will equal, the second provided example in the question itself, 
thank @ibrahim and the correct answer belongs to him.

Comment: There's no 'typecasting' that takes place here, though.

Comment: Agree with @pvg. Although there is still some mysteries on how it works exactly. I couldn't find anything. It could be typecasting but I don't think so.